# Computer not switching on swithed power button

Tags: boot, hardware-failure, power

My computer is not powering on when i push power button, I tried cleaning the power slot of motherboard and tried changing the SMPS (PSU) of the machine, Even then the computer is not powering on. But the LED is glowing in the motherboard.

Comment: What is SMPS? Also, did it stop working before you cleaned it or after?

Comment: You need to ensure all the PSU connectors are connected correctly to the motherboard. When you press the power button, do any other LED's come one, does the CPU fan spin? Does the PSU fan spin? If the PSU fan doesn't spin, the issue is the PSU

Comment: @edvinas.me SMPS is PSU. It stopped before cleaning.

Comment: @DaveRook No LEDs, CPU fan or PSU fan spins when i press power button

Comment: So, you are getting totally no response... sounds like the issue is with the power cable to the PSU, or with the plug (the fuse has gone) or the plug socket on the wall...

Comment: Check if you didn't acidentally disconnect small pins for power buttons to work. If not, it might be failed Motherboard or CPU. Also, make sure to remove RAM and disconnect other un-necessary peripherals.

Comment: Ok... i am checking it now.after i solve the problem i will let know.
Thanks friends... :)

Answer (score 0):

The power issues like that are most of the time due to failed Power Supply Unit (PSU). There is a small chance that there might also be problems with your motherboard (due to failed PSU), first think you need to do is get different Power Supply Unit.

Before getting a new one from the store I would try to swap-in one from a working computer just to confirm that it's only PSU that has failed.

**Update**

If you swapped the PSU and this did not help, make sure that you plugged everything in well. Also double-check the small plugs for Power Button to work, maybe these got disconnected and your power button is not working due to tiny pins being not attached or attached incorrectly?

If you motherboard LEDs are on, but you still can't power it on and you are sure that your PSU is good and is connected well, then it can be CPU or MotherBoard failing.

Also, make sure to remove RAM and disconnect other not necessary peripherals when testing everything.

Comment: Yes, i tried swapping the PSU from working machine.But it did not work.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally solved the problem.
The cable that connects power button to motherboard was broken.i replaced it with new new cable...Working quite fine & back to normal...

anyhow thanks folks...